# How can I remove the pipe delimiter in JasperReports Server's input controls?

Tags: jasperserver

Where can I go to remove the pipe delimiter when specifying multiple visible fields in an input control?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can only give you a pointer as I haven't yet needed to do this...
For each report there is a customization point enabling you to override the default presentation for Input Controls, where you can nominate an alternative JSP to do this.
There should be some documentation with JasperReports Server to show how to do this.